# Upload files to solr in C#

Tags: c#, database, file-upload, solr, interface

I am trying to make an application in **Windows Form Application** in **C#**. In my project I have added **solr**. I will upload files **(json, xml, csv, txt, or database)** and I will do the searching. I can do the filtering or searching by using solr in C#. However, the problem is I can't **submit** or **upload the files** to the system. For instance, I want to **upload a database** to the system. I have already done the query part so that I will do the filtering and searching. But as I said I can't do the file upload part.

I am doing my interface in C# so that I will not use the solr interface. Thats why, I need to submit/upload choosen file when button pressed. 
Is there any way to do that? 
Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try uploading file to server & instead of saving file to the database!
while uploading a file, convert it into zip & then save it to the server folder, & save path of the file in the table.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I am not saving files into a database. I want to submit database -or other types of files- to solr and then I will do searching and filtering for those files.